# Program(s) keep running periodically in command prompt. How can I stop this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, spyware

Every now and then, some program opens a terminal. I'm trying to figure out what this is as it's becoming really annoying (and somewhat worrisome).

I can see in windows' Event Scheduler that a few programs attempt to run, including these every 20 minutes (in xml form):

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-19T04:03:06.422265400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>117114</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyLaptop</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>CLR20r3</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>GfxDownloadWrapper.exe</Data> 
  <Data>8.15.100.6471</Data> 
  <Data>5c0eb8ef</Data> 
  <Data>mscorlib</Data> 
  <Data>4.7.3362.0</Data> 
  <Data>5c2fce36</Data> 
  <Data>1688</Data> 
  <Data>fd</Data> 
  <Data>System.IO.DirectoryNotFound</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD86F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_GfxDownloadWrapp_63de6f31988f828df11124e686818bf7f7595a2_208c66a7_7eddd68b</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>176e9a2d-37f8-4a1a-a03c-0e7909f7656e</Data> 
  <Data>102</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and this:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-19T04:24:55.126744300Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>117126</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyLaptop</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>StoreAgentInstallFailure1</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>Acquisition;DSIC</Data> 
  <Data>80073cf9</Data> 
  <Data>17763</Data> 
  <Data>475</Data> 
  <Data>Windows.Desktop</Data> 
  <Data>Z</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERA231.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_Acquisition;DSIC_9a1a5ea0fd4a141a18acff403764216a223d81f_00000000_2a3ba1b4</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>526108f9-bb17-4da9-b866-328cb3e73aa3</Data> 
  <Data>102</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

And this:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-19T04:24:55.104802800Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>117125</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyLaptop</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>StoreAgentSearchUpdatePackagesFailure1</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>Acquisition;DSIC</Data> 
  <Data>803fb005</Data> 
  <Data>17763</Data> 
  <Data>475</Data> 
  <Data>Windows.Desktop</Data> 
  <Data>T</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER8478.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_Acquisition;DSIC_cfc3ab64b62e54274710a733fa60c4e6ef6c831_00000000_2a3b842a</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>8ea9b609-7593-46ce-b8dd-cec835e01047</Data> 
  <Data>102</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

The only one I can recognize is `GfxDownloadWrapper.exe`, which is from intel, but I'm not sure. I don't know what the others are and why I have to see this happen all the time, and honestly speaking I'm worried it's some kind of spyware or something. How can I stop these from running like this?

Comment: That looks like Wndow error reporting. ...

Comment: Run Process Monitor for a while just processes, you can disable file/registry and network and drop filtered events. After you see the issue, stop the capture and look at the process tree to see what process it was and who luanched it. The other option which is similar is to install Sysmon (Sysinternals/Microsoft again) this can log to the Event log all processes being launched. I would go for Process Monitor if you know it will happen in say 20 mins but Sysmon if it could take hours. It could be WER kicking in to handle a process crashing but the logs/traces from the above will show this.

Comment: @HelpingHand How can I show only processes in Process Monitor? I couldn't find an option for that.

Comment: It always creates the Process tree, but you can add a filter for Operation = Process Create and Process Start.